# create multiple datasets in loop to transform them into list

Tags: pandas, list, loops

I have, suppose, the following dataset df:

```
data = {'Logic':['Social', 'H&S', 'General', 'Social', 'Social', 'General'], 'Var1':['Wage', 'Health', 'Strike', 'Bonus' ,  'Hours', 'Protest'],
        'Var2':[23,75,45, 32,13,14]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df has a column named Logic. In the column, there are 3 unique values:'Social', 'H&S', 'General'

I am trying to create 3 different lists, one for each of the unique values of df['Logic'], each containing the values in their respective rows in df. My outcome would be:

> General = ['Strike', 'Protest', 45, 14] H&S = ['Health', 75]  Social =
>   etc. etc...

What I have tried so far:

```
list_lexi = df['Logic'].tolist()
for i in list_lexi:
    i = lexi[lexi['Logic']==i].iloc[:,1:].values.tolist()
```

But I understand I cannot simply create a new list inside a loop.

Any suggestion?

Also, if I were to rename each list as per the unique value + '_list' (e.g. Social_list), how would I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
gb = df.groupby('Logic')
gb.apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Logic').melt().value.tolist()).to_dict()
```

the output:

```
{'General': ['Strike', 'Protest', 45, 14],
 'H&S': ['Health', 75],
 'Social': ['Wage', 'Bonus', 'Hours', 23, 32, 13]}
```

Comment: looks great, but I understand these are lists inside a dataframe rather than being lists. My ideal output is two have three lists not as part of a dataframe.

Comment: I edited to post, added .to_dict(), which would change dataframe to dictionary. I think you can change it to lists from here.

Comment: for future references, is to_dict(), not todict()

Comment: you are right, I typed it wrong when editing, fixed. so this is what you want?

Comment: yes, thanks, i confirmed the this is useful solution.